# Set color on get (json) angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have this table => [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEOmi.png)

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let list of lists">
<caption>{{ list.nodename }}</caption>
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Название сервиса</th>
       <th>Статус</th>        
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.servicelist">
            <td>{{ service_rec.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_rec.status }}</td>      
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My task to set a color - `green = online`, `red = offline`, but i don't have any idea how! :( Help, plz.

I get data on this json

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this._service.getServices()
                .subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
}
```

and this

```
getServices(){
    return this._http.get(this._url)
                    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I assume you want something like.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.servicelist" >
        <td>{{ service_rec.name }}</td>
        <td [style.background-color]="service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'">{{ service_rec.status }}</td>      
    </tr>
```

Comment: ser a color column "Статус" if Online - column online is green, and if Offline - column offline is red

Comment: You didn't mention in your question it's about column. My answer sets the color for rows. How do I know it is online or offline?

Comment: click on image. OK, how to set a color only column?

Comment: I don't see color in the linked image.

Comment: yes, of course! this table dont have any colors. my task - to set a color(green, red) only columns "Статус"

Comment: and now all columns are red

Comment: anf if i want to set a some style? such as label label-success and label label-danger? what should i do?

Comment: What is `label-success` or `label-danger`? A class? Then use `[class.label-danger]="trueOrFalseValue"` or `[ngClass]="{label-danger: trueOrFalseValue}"`

Comment: yes, ist a class (class="label label-success"), but how i use it with my code?

Comment: How should I know? Please provide more information.

Comment: OK. You set a color of column, and now, taks is to set a some bootstrap style (class="label label-success" and class="label label-danger") with color green and red.

Comment: Just replace `trueOrFalseValue` with `service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'`

Comment: but need for Online - green,  label label-success, and for Offline - red, label label-danger

Comment: Then switch the values `service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'red' : 'green'` for one of `label-danger` or `label-success`. This is simple JS there is no Angular magic. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: i add this code `[class.label-danger]="service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'"` , and all my columns being are red

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `[class.label-danger]="service_rec.status == 'Online'"` It's all explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html though

Comment: and if i want add a button, on depending online or offline? how syntax this?